# Is it possible to either bind a key within LUA or to prevent a IsMouseButtonPressed from reading a PressAndReleaseMouseButton event?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

As the title suggests, I need to be able to do one of two things, but don't know how to do either. Basically my problem is that I can't use "IsMouseButtonPressed(1)" to determine whether to execute a portion of a script if the script itself it using "PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)".

So, I either need a way to make my mouse button do something else during the script, or I need to prevent "IsMouseButtonPressed(1)" from reading an induced mouse click. I really just want it to check the state of the physical mouse. Is this possible? I am using LUA within Logitech Gaming Software.

EDIT: I am adding an example of my code using what I learned from Joseph. I do not know why this doesn't work. Luckily, there aren't any errors.

```
local fakePressStatus = {}

local function IsMouseButtonReallyPressed(b)
    return fakePressStatus[b] == nil and IsMouseButtonPressed(b)
end

local function FakePressAndReleaseMouseButton(b)
    fakePressStatus[b] = (fakePressStatus[b] or 0) + 1
    PressAndReleaseMouseButton(b)
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" then
        if fakePressStatus[b] == 1 then
            fakePressStatus[b] = nil
        elseif fakePressStatus[b] ~= nil then
            fakePressStatus[b] = fakePressStatus[b] - 1
        end
    end

    if IsMouseButtonReallyPressed(1) then
        for i = 0, 10 do
            if IsMouseButtonReallyPressed(1) then
                FakePressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
                Sleep (100)
            else
                i = 10
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set variables that keep track of fake presses/releases, like this:

```
local fakePressStatus = {}

local function IsMouseButtonReallyPressed(b)
    return fakePressStatus[b] == nil and IsMouseButtonPressed(b)
end

local function FakePressAndReleaseMouseButton(b)
    fakePressStatus[b] = (fakePressStatus[b] or 0) + 1
    PressAndReleaseMouseButton(b)
end

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" then
        if fakePressStatus[b] == 1 then
            fakePressStatus[b] = nil
        elseif fakePressStatus[b] ~= nil then
            fakePressStatus[b] = fakePressStatus[b] - 1
        end
    end
end
```

Then just use `FakePressAndReleaseMouseButton` and `IsMouseButtonReallyPressed` in place of `PressAndReleaseMouseButton` and `IsMouseButtonPressed` everywhere.

Comment: This looks like it could be awesome! However, it returns "[string "LuaVM"]:18: attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' (a nil value)". I went ahead and threw this into an isolated profile to ensure it's nothing from my existing code, but the error persisted. I'll update here if I find a solution, but otherwise I'd appreciate your input. Thanks in advance. EDIT: To clarify, the error only appears when attempting to execute the code by causing the mouse button released event. It saves fine initially.

Comment: @Yuiop In the file you got that error from, which line is line 18?

Comment: fakePressStatus[b] = fakePressStatus[b] - 1 (I forgot that I left the default comment in there so it messed with the line count, sorry)

Comment: It fixed the error! However, it doesn't seem to work for some reason. I went ahead and made a simplified form of what I'm doing. I'll edit my original post with it since it is exceeds the character limit for a comment.

Comment: @Yuiop Why do you have two calls to `IsMouseButtonReallyPressed`? Does it work if you get rid of the one inside the loop?

Comment: In my head, the first one initiates the process, and the second is a constant check to allow for immediate termination, but it may have been unnecessary. I only built it that way to show what I'm up to. It fails to work regardless, even if I remove the repeating portion. I'm using a click speed testing site to prove that it really isn't working.

Comment: @Yuiop How about if you add `EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)` like I just did?

Comment: I actually already had that in the full version of my code, but for the heck of it I threw it into this and still no go. I feel like your code should work, but it's gotta be some small thing.

Comment: After further inspection, I think I see the problem. The function `IsMouseButtonReallyPressed` relies on `IsMouseButtonPressed` being true. Sure, it involves another variable now as well, but the whole problem is that I can't get `IsMouseButtonPressed` to be true following `PressAndReleaseMouseButton` in the first place. Any ideas? Also, the functions themselves didn't work until I moved them into `function OnEvent (event, arg)`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to prevent "IsMouseButtonPressed(1)" from reading an induced mouse click

It's impossible.

But there is a workaround: you can add alternative button for the same action as LMB.
For example, if LMB means "Fire" then add key "P" as alternative way to fire in the game.

```
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
    for i = 0, 10 do
        Sleep (100)
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end 
        PressKey("P")
        Sleep (20)
        ReleaseKey("P")
    end
end
```

You make the first shot by pressing LMB, and the script will make 2nd, 3rd,... shots by programmatically pressing <kbd>P</kbd> in the loop.